# CKeditor: Cannot add .PNG image to my custom button in my toolbar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor

I created custom button to for uploading my files from database. I have downloaded the image for my button in my ckeditor/plugins/plugin.js but it does not show up when in run the website. Here is how my plugin.js looks like:

> ```
> CKEDITOR.plugins.add('testimage',
> {
>   requires: ['iframedialog'],
>   init: function (editor) {
>   editor.addCommand('testimage', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('testimage')); // associating the executable code with the button
>   editor.ui.addButton('testimage',
>    {
>     label: 'Upload Image',
>     command: 'testimage',
>     icon: this.path + 'Expanding-image-mouse-out.png'
>    });
>     CKEDITOR.dialog.addIframe('testimage', 'upload image', '/Upload/UploadImage', 500, 400);
>    }
> });
> ```

```
 function closedialog(url) {

   CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().hide();

 }
   function setText(image_path, id, toolNum) {
     CKEDITOR.instances.CKE.insertHtml('<img src=\x22' + image_path + '\x22 border=0 id=image' + id + '>');
     var element = CKEDITOR.instances.CKE.document.getById('image' + id);
     CKEDITOR.instances.CKE.getSelection().selectElement(element);
      getToolbar(toolNum);

}
    function getToolbar(num) {

   CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(num, this); return false;

 }
```

I do not see the image on my button but button is doing all its assigned function. Please Tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: well this is frustrating. The .png has to be of 16X16 pixels to show up properly. I have changed the pixels of the file and now it's showing up properly.

Comment: Put your solution in an answer, so someone with the same problem will notice it in the future. You should also accept your answer by clicking the check mark next to it since it's the correct answer to the question.